# Merging two XMLDOMDocuments

Tags: merge, msxml, ixmldomdocument

Is there any easy way in msxml to merge two xml documents (IXMLDomDocuments)?
I want to make one of the trees embedded as a child of the second one.

I saw that IXMLDomDocument3 offers importNode, but couldn't get it to work correctly. Is this the way to go or is there another solution?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

What programming language are you using?

Here's a working example in Javascript:

Given A.xml:

```
<base>
  <A>
    <one>
      <two/>
    </one>
  </A>
</base>
```

B.xml:

```
<something>
  <B/>
  <BBBBBB/>
</something>
```

merge.js:

```
var doc1 = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument");
doc1.load("A.xml");
var doc2 = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument");
doc2.load("B.xml");
doc1.documentElement.appendChild(doc2.documentElement);
WScript.echo (doc1.xml);
```

The output is:

```
<base>
  <A>
    <one>
      <two/>
    </one>
  </A>
  <something>
    <B/>
    <BBBBBB/>
  </something>
</base>
```